# How can we find $[GF(p^n):GF(p)]=n$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I was searching why $[GF(p^n):GF(p)]=n$. It is not very logical, isn't it ? I know that $$GF(p^n)=\{x\in GF(p)^{alg}\mid x^{p^n}=x \}$$
is a field with $p^n$ element since it split $X^{p^n}-X$ which is separable. But how can we get an irreducible polynomial in $GF(p)$ of degree $n$ and that split over $GF(p^n)$ ?

Comment: All irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ in $\mathbb F_p$ split in $\mathbb F_{p^n}$

Comment: Can you give me just one ? @CuddlyCuttlefish

Comment: $x^5+x^3+1$ (this should be irreducible) splits in $\mathbb F_{2^5}$

Comment: and how would you prove the assertion in general ?@CuddlyCuttlefish

Comment: and why it must divide $x^{p^n}-x$ ? it's not obvious !

Comment: I am not sure where you are confused; if you have an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, then it splits in a degree $n$ extension.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1557997/11619), or one of the several earlier incarnations of essentially this same question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple formula for an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$. 
The fact that the degree of the extension is $n$ is immediate for reasons of cardinality.

You said correctly the cardinality of $GF(p^n)$ is $p^n$. And the cardinality of a vectorspace of dimension $d$ over $GF(p)$ is $p^d$. Thus the dimension of $GF(p^n)$ as a $GF(p)$ vectorspace must be $n$.